# GUI interface for online handwriting recognition in MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, mouse, handwriting-recognition

I need to create a GUI interface from which I can get x and y coordinate and pen-up/pen-down stroke value of points as input from the user. The user uses mouse to draw the text or non-text characters. How can I create such a GUI interface using MATLAB?